# How to set a file type to open and edit in a different program

Tags: windows-8, file-association

In previous versions of Windows, I was able to set file types to open and edit in different programs (for example, HTML files would open in Firefox, but edit in TotalEdit).

I can't find a way to do that in Windows 8 (Pro). Does anyone know if it is possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right Mouseclick the file
2. Select 'Open With'
3. Select 'Choose default program...'
4. Make sure the checkbox 'Use the program for all ... files' is enabled and select the program you want to open it with.

Just right mouse click and select the one from the 'open with' list you want to use.

Comment: This isn't the answer since it does not cover the `Edit` context command. Better is the answer from @Michael.

Answer (score 2):

I have already done something like this using [DefaultProgramsEditor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/).